# Oracle 12.2 - getting ORA-14427 when trying to partition a table with XMLTYPE column

Tags: xml, oracle, partitioning, xmltype

I am currently partitioning existing tables on my database. Some of them have XMLType columns and it seems that ALTER TABLE .. MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE ... ONLINE does not work on these tables.

I've tested following scenario: create table with XMLType column, try to partition it (failed), remove XMLTYpe column and then table can be partitioned:

```
create table t_tab (t_id number (38) generated always as identity primary key,
t_content xmltype,
t_date date);
--Table T_TAB created.

insert into t_tab (t_content, t_date)
values ('<xml>
<item>
    <A>'||'A'||'</A>
    <B>'||'B'||'</B>
</item></xml>', 
sysdate);
insert into t_tab (t_content, t_date)
values ('<xml>
<item>
    <C>'||'C'||'</C>
    <D>'||'D'||'</D>

</item></xml>', 
sysdate-77);
insert
into t_tab (t_content, t_date)
values ('<xml>
<item>
    <E>'||'E'||'</E>
    <F>'||'F'||'</F>

</item></xml>', 
sysdate-40);
commit;
--1 row inserted.
--1 row inserted.
--1 row inserted.
--Commit complete.


ALTER TABLE t_tab MODIFY
     PARTITION BY RANGE (
          t_date
     ) INTERVAL ( numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH') ) ( PARTITION PRT_START
          VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('2007-10-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
          ) )
     )
ONLINE;
--ORA-14427: table does not support modification to a partitioned state DDL.

alter table t_tab drop column t_content;
--Table T_TAB altered.

ALTER TABLE t_tab MODIFY
     PARTITION BY RANGE (
          t_date
     ) INTERVAL ( numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH') ) ( PARTITION PRT_START
          VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('2007-10-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
          ) )
     )
ONLINE;
--Table T_TAB altered.

select table_name, partitioned from dba_tables where table_name='T_TAB';
T_NAME   IS_PRT
-------- ---
T_TAB    YES
```

I expected these tables to be partitioned, but it seems that XMLType blocks it. Does anyone here have the same experience?

Answer (score 0):

The `ORA-14427` error implies that the table was already partitioned.  You may want to invoke each command again using a different table name.  When I ran your statements in [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=722e4ed52a5046ef6931e487d4c0530c) I get a `ORA-00922` (missing or invalid option).  Check your syntax.

Comment: Syntax seems to be fine, I run those statement is all my databases without ORA-00922.

Comment: And the table has never been partitioned. XMLType seems to be a blocker here. I'll try to report it to Oracle, it might be just another bug.